# Logrotation in openshift apache - not working

Tags: apache, openshift, logrotate

I am trying to rotate the apache logs in openshift using logrotate.

While trying to test the logrotate functionality, its giving me the below error

logrotate -d httpd

where httpd is the file present in /etc/logrotate.d

error: Logrotate UID is not in passwd file.
error: error creating state file /var/lib/..../logrotate.status

Please let me know if there is a fix to this or even logrotation is possible in openshift ?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using logrotate witin a container. In general, you should not use log files within a container and should always log to `stdout`.

This is a best practice from the [Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/logs) and OpenShift comes with its own Logging Stack to handle the logs.